# Trying to create a script editor code for sheet3 only

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm trying to make a Y/N popup box appear when you open the sheet3 on a Googlesheet file. So far I have this code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Have you sorted the Calculations Page?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Thank you, you may continue.');
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Please sort the Order Number column.');
  }
}
```

But with this code, it applies when I open the document, and only when I open the document. I'd like it so the box appears when I open the sheet3 tab. Extra points if there is a way to take me to sheet2 if you click 'No' on the box!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. However, you might want to use a helper sheet that uses the `=SORT()` function to automatically sort the Calculations Page... It's one of the super simple but highly effective functions in Google sheets

Comment: Ok, thats a shame about the script editor. So, what exactly do I do in order to make that auto Sort happen? In the calculations page there are a number of different order numbers in Collumn A. How would the sort function work there?

Comment: Just include the whole range and select which sort column(s) to sort on `=SORT([data], 1, true)`

More here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en

Comment: That won't unfortuantly work in my case as the data it's sorting carries a lot of data that doesn't get sorted by mearly sorting Collumn A. It almost worked though!

Comment: You can sort on more than the one column, just add them and say whether they should be ascending or descending `=SORT([data], 1, true, 5, false, 3, true, ...)`

Comment: It's probably easier to link you a version of the sheet I'm working with so you can see what I mean (hopefully). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xo4YLPaViacOsfjAt95j9TXvD26IN4f36XcKPxz-hRY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Create a new sheet called CALCULATIONS_SORTED, then in A2 put `=SORT(FILTER(CALCULATIONS!A2:R,LEN(CALCULATIONS!A2:A)),1,TRUE)`. Then you can change the references in COPY THIS accordingly to point to the new sheet.

Comment: Doing that unfortuantly won't help, as the reason why they need to be in numerical order is becuase of certain calculations done on the CALCULATIONS tab. It's ok, I won't worry about doing this yet, it was only supposed to be a quick easy of life thing. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: no prob. Still think it's doable though. Just make sure to turn off the sharing for the document before adding sensitive data back to it.

Comment: You could maybe sort this through a script. Have you considered that? Are you familiar with Apps Script?